# Matlab code for definite positive -1/1 matrix

Tags: matlab

Could anybody tell me how to generate a random sign (-1/1) definite positive matrix in Matlab ?

Update: Thanks to all who replied, that was very helpful

I am experimenting compressed sensing using l1 Magic with different sensing matrices, Gaussian worked well but with Bernoulli, l1 Magic gives me an "matrix must be definite positive" error that's why I was asking my question

Comment: Of which dimensions? What did you try?

Comment: 64-by-64, I tried a=sign(randn(64,64)); didn't work

Comment: How is this supposed to ensure that the matrix is positive definite? Do you want a symmetric matrix...?

Comment: I'm sorry but what you're asking for is not possible.  There will be high probability that one row can be expressed in terms of another row if you only have `+1/-1`, which means that your matrix is not full rank, which means that your matrix will not be positive definite.

Comment: Just `1` and `-1` or is `0` allowed too?

Comment: I can try 0's too, I am experimenting compressed sensing using l1 Magic with different sensing matrices, Gaussian worked well but with Bernoulli, l1 Magic gives me an "matrix must be definite positive" error

Comment: Then `A = sign(2*rand(64)-1);` `A = (A+A.')/2;`.

Comment: If you can introduce 0s, then what @horchler suggested will work.  Strictly using `-1/1` will not give you what you desire though.

Comment: @MohabMostafa I suggest you edit your question with details you have provided in the comments to prevent it from being closed or getting more down-votes.

Comment: @horchler that doesn't generate a positive definite matrix. The eigenvalues can be negative

Comment: @rayryeng The only matrix i've found that is positive definite and has elements in {-1, 0, 1} is the identity matrix! From my testing, it's not just improbable, it's straight up impossible to find what he's asking for.

Comment: @MatthewGunn nice post! Thanks for confirming my instincts!

Comment: @MatthewGunn: Yep. That's just how to make `A` symmetric. I forgot the extra step to make it positive definite which of course then has values outside the range. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really good answer would require more knowledge about the exact requirements and context. From what I've read:

#### What you're asking for may be doable for non-symmetric matrices

As [horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278029/horchler) pointed out,

```
A = [1, 0, 0
     0, 1, 0
    -1, 1, 1];
```

has all positive eigenvalues, hence is positive definite.

How to find these efficiently for large sized matrices seems to me a non-trivial problem, but I don't really know.

#### What you're asking for does not appear possible for symmetric matrices

- Restricting entries to the set {-1,1}, there are NO 2x2 or 3x3 or 4x4 or 5x5 or 6x6 positive definite matrices.
- Restricting entries to the set {-1, 0, 1}, the ONLY positive definite matrices that I've found, by enumerating all possibilities, are the identity matrix! I'd conjecture it's impossible for any size matrix, but I don't know for sure.

Brute force enumeration of 2x2 symmetric matrices:

```
[-1, -1       eigenvalues -2, 0
 -1, -1]   

[-1, -1       eigenvalues -1.4, 1.4
 -1,  1]   

[-1,  1       eigenvalues -2, 0
  1, -1]   

[-1,  1       eigenvalues -1.4, 1.4
  1,  1]   

[1,   1       eigenvalues 0, 2
 1,   1]   

[1,   1       eigenvalues -1.4, 1.4
 1,   -1]   

[1,   -1       eigenvalues 0, 2
 -1,   1]   

[1,   -1       eigenvalues -1.4, 1.4
 -1,   -1]
```

Comment: Looks like you posted two identical answers.  Delete one and I'll vote on the other!

Comment: @rayryeng Ooops, I've done this before mistakenly. Something like hitting the back button and editing seems to generate multiple posts.

Comment: `A = [1,0,0;0,1,0;-1,1,1];` is full rank and has all positive eigenvalues (all `1`). There are other examples. And FYI, the best way to check if a matrix is positive definite is `[~,p] = chol(A);`.

Comment: @horchler not symmetric!

Comment: @MatthewGunn: Yes, but the OP didn't indicate that it had to be symmetric.